# RuntimeException at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I have this crash that gets reported quite often on Play Console, but I can't reproduce it on my devices, and I'm not really sure what the cause is because the stack trace doesn't seem to be complete

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3635)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: Is there any specific Android version where it crashes?

Comment: @SujalKumar Well 73.5% of crashes are on Android 11, 12.2% on Android 12, 10.7% on Android 10 and 3.6% on Android 9.

Comment: I had this crash when I pasted an image asset to drawable-v24 folder and after launching the app. Google distribute folder and our icon is not in a lot of apks